# Independent t-test of DataFrame columns, grouping by another column?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, t-test, scipy.stats

I have the following DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
 'Chemical': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'A', 3: 'A', 4: 'A', 5: 'B', 6: 'B', 7: 'B', 8: 'B', 9: 'B', 10: 'C', 11: 'C', 12: 'C', 13: 'C', 14: 'C', 15: 'D', 16: 'D', 17: 'D', 18: 'D', 19: 'D', 20: 'E', 21: 'E', 22: 'E', 23: 'E', 24: 'E', 25: 'F', 26: 'F', 27: 'F', 28: 'F', 29: 'F'},
 'Con': {0: 4.3, 1: 4.6, 2: 6.0, 3: 3.4, 4: 5.4, 5: 3.7, 6: 7.3, 7: 7.1, 8: 6.3, 9: 6.9, 10: 13.2, 11: 15.2, 12: 17.4, 13: 14.9, 14: 15.0, 15: 30.5, 16: 30.4, 17: 30.8, 18: 40.2, 19: 50.1, 20: 210.0, 21: 215.0, 22: 220.0, 23: 212.0, 24: 282.0, 25: 4.5, 26: 4.9, 27: 5.1, 28: 3.2, 29: 8.2},
 'Test': {0: 6.3, 1: 6.6, 2: 8.0, 3: 5.4, 4: 7.4, 5: 5.7, 6: 9.3, 7: 9.1, 8: 8.3, 9: 8.9, 10: 15.2, 11: 17.2, 12: 19.4, 13: 16.9, 14: 17.0, 15: 32.5, 16: 32.4, 17: 32.8, 18: 42.2, 19: 52.1, 20: 220.0, 21: 225.0, 22: 230.0, 23: 222.0, 24: 292.0, 25: 6.5, 26: 6.9, 27: 7.1, 28: 5.2, 29: 10.2},
 }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to perform an independent sample t-test using [scipy.stats.ttest_ind](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html) to compare the mean of the values in column `Test` to the mean of the values in column `Con` *when `Chemical` is the same*. So in essence, compare `Con` v `Test` when `Chemical = A`, then `Con` v `Test` when `Chem = B`, and so on. Then output the *p*-values for each comparison.

I can't for the life of me work out how to do this in an efficient way. I've thought about using `groupby` on `Chemical` before applying the test, but I couldn't get that to work. I've also toyed with the following code, but still no luck:

```
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind
results = []

for df in chemical:
    scipy.stats.ttest_ind(x['Con'], x['Test'], equal_var=False)
    print(f'chemical compared')
    analytes.append(results)
```

How can I do this efficiently?

Comment: Please provide the expected output

Comment: Also your code is ambiguous, what is `analytes`? what is `x`?

Comment: Apologies, analytes should be chemical, and x should be the dataframe (or the chemical being compared).

Comment: And the expected outcome would be something like: A Con vs Test p = value; B Con vs Test p=  value and so forth

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same number of observations in each group and they are already sorted by group as shown:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats

data = {
 'Chemical': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'A', 3: 'A', 4: 'A', 5: 'B', 6: 'B', 7: 'B', 8: 'B', 9: 'B', 10: 'C', 11: 'C', 12: 'C', 13: 'C', 14: 'C', 15: 'D', 16: 'D', 17: 'D', 18: 'D', 19: 'D', 20: 'E', 21: 'E', 22: 'E', 23: 'E', 24: 'E', 25: 'F', 26: 'F', 27: 'F', 28: 'F', 29: 'F'},
 'Con': {0: 4.3, 1: 4.6, 2: 6.0, 3: 3.4, 4: 5.4, 5: 3.7, 6: 7.3, 7: 7.1, 8: 6.3, 9: 6.9, 10: 13.2, 11: 15.2, 12: 17.4, 13: 14.9, 14: 15.0, 15: 30.5, 16: 30.4, 17: 30.8, 18: 40.2, 19: 50.1, 20: 210.0, 21: 215.0, 22: 220.0, 23: 212.0, 24: 282.0, 25: 4.5, 26: 4.9, 27: 5.1, 28: 3.2, 29: 8.2},
 'Test': {0: 6.3, 1: 6.6, 2: 8.0, 3: 5.4, 4: 7.4, 5: 5.7, 6: 9.3, 7: 9.1, 8: 8.3, 9: 8.9, 10: 15.2, 11: 17.2, 12: 19.4, 13: 16.9, 14: 17.0, 15: 32.5, 16: 32.4, 17: 32.8, 18: 42.2, 19: 52.1, 20: 220.0, 21: 225.0, 22: 230.0, 23: 222.0, 24: 292.0, 25: 6.5, 26: 6.9, 27: 7.1, 28: 5.2, 29: 10.2},
 }
 
n_per_group = 5
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# reshape columns to (6, 5) array, one row per group
con = df['Con'].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 5)
test = df['Test'].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 5)

# perform t-test along corresponding rows
res = stats.ttest_ind(con, test, axis=-1, equal_var=False)

# TtestResult(
#     statistic=array([-3.14970394, -2.13784562, -2.11382952, -0.36255927, -0.51786368, -1.71574296]), 
#     pvalue=array([0.01360455, 0.0649941 , 0.06747004, 0.72632566, 0.61856595, 0.12454701]), 
#     df=array([8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8.])
# )
```

This will probably be the most performant option because no Python loops are used under the hood.

If you don't have the same number of observations in each group, or if they aren't sorted and you don't want to sort them:

```py
grouped = df.groupby('Chemical')

def f(df):
    return pd.Series(stats.ttest_ind(df['Con'], df['Test']),
                     index=['statistic', 'pvalue'])

grouped.apply(f)
```

[image]

Another option is [`ttest_ind_from_stats`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind_from_stats.html), which might be useful in some circumstances.

```py
grouped = df.groupby('Chemical')
mean1 = grouped['Con'].mean()
mean2 = grouped['Test'].mean()
std1 = grouped['Con'].std()
std2 = grouped['Test'].std()
nobs1 = grouped['Con'].count()
nobs2 = grouped['Test'].count()
stats.ttest_ind_from_stats(mean1, std1, nobs1, mean2, std2, nobs2, equal_var=False)

# Ttest_indResult(statistic=Chemical
# A   -3.149704
# B   -2.137846
# C   -2.113830
# D   -0.362559
# E   -0.517864
# F   -1.715743
# dtype: float64, pvalue=Chemical
# A    0.013605
# B    0.064994
# C    0.067470
# D    0.726326
# E    0.618566
# F    0.124547
# dtype: float64)
```